# MySQL cumulative count open items

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have the below table:

```
id      reference   created_at              closed_at
__      ______      ___________             __________
1       62506       2017-01-09 12:05:34     2017-01-09 16:14:55
2       62507       2017-01-09 12:09:47     NULL
3       62508       2017-01-10 12:09:48     NULL
4       62509       2017-01-10 12:11:15     NULL
5       62510       2017-01-10 12:12:41     2017-01-12 13:52:04
6       62511       2017-01-11 12:18:01     NULL
7       62512       2017-01-11 12:20:26     2017-01-15 11:39:31
8       62513       2017-01-11 12:29:19     NULL
9       62514       2017-01-12 12:37:11     NULL
10      62515       2017-01-12 12:43:31     NULL
11      62516       2017-01-12 13:20:49     NULL
12      62517       2017-01-12 13:30:58     2017-01-12 17:36:24
```

I would like a query that returns a rolling total of items and also how many we have 'open' that day (open being null in closed_at or a close date greater than the results rows date)

```
somedate     Total  Open
----------   ------ -----
2017-01-09   2      1      
2017-01-10   5      4
2017-01-11   8      7
2017-01-12   12     10
```

I know i need to do some kind of cumulative count, but i'm rubbish and need your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one easy method.  Get the unique dates and then use correlated subqueries:

```
select d.dte,
       (select count(*) from t where t.created_at < d.dte + interval 1 day
       ) as total,
       (select count(*) from t where t.closed_at < d.dte + interval 1 day
       ) as closed,
       (select count(*) from t
        where t.created_at < d.dte + interval 1 day and
              (t.closed_at is null or t.closed_at >= d.dte + interval 1 day)
       ) as total
from (select date(created_at) as dte from t
      union -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      select date(closed_at) from t
     ) d;
```

The `+ interval 1 day` is so the "day" is as of midnight of the day.

The lack of `date()` on the comparisons is so the correlated subqueries can use indexes.

The `union` in the subquery is so all dates with activity are counted, even if there are no new items (only closed items).

Comment: That's exactly what i'm looking for, thanks. I really need to brush up on my sql, i know the basics up to say aggregates, but when you start getting into stuff like correlated subqueries it goes over my head, any advice on books or tutorials to follow to level up a bit?

Comment: @Lovatt Just stick around here for a bit. You'll soon get the hang of it.